# Color of isosurface in charge density visualization

Tags: crystallography, visualization-software, vesta, charge-density

I am trying to visualize the charge density of a crystal through VESTA. However the intersection surface of the isosurface and the boundary turns into blue, which is certainly not included in my settings. Is there a way to turn it off for black-and-white settings? [image]